# Transpose of derivative operator acting on Dirac delta

Tags: vector-spaces, dirac-delta, transpose

I was reading a text where the transpose $A^T: V^\ast \to V^\ast$ of a linear operator $A: V\to V$ on vector space $V$ was defined as follows $(A^Tf)(v) = f(Av)$ with $f \in V^\ast, v \in V$.  (So not the adjoint, no inner product was introduced yet).  This was then used to illustrate that the derivative of the Dirac delta linear functional gives $$\left( \frac{d^T}{dx} \delta  \right)[f(x)] = \delta[\frac{df(x)}{dx}] = f'(0).$$

How does this square with the usual $\delta' [f(x)] = -f'(0)$ in analogy to general Schwartz distributions (where the minus sign arises from the partial integration analogy)?

Comment: The relation you wrote is not the derivative of the dirac delta, it's the transpose of the derivative. So, the derivative of a dirac delta applied on a function $f$ gives you $-f^{'} (0)$. While the transpose of the derivative, applied on $f$ gives you $f^{'} (0)$.

Comment: Yes, but strictly speaking the derivative is defined on $V$ and not on $V^*$ so not on the dirac delta functional.  I guess in the second case one should also consider the map linking vectors with duals through the bilinear form:  $L : V \to V^* v \mapsto  \tilde{v} = \langle v | . \rangle$.  And then there can be a derivative considered on $V^*$ with $ \frac{d}{dx} \circ L^{-1}$.  But for the Dirac delta is $L^{-1} (\delta)$ properly defined..?

Comment: Can you provide the source of your definition?

Comment: Source was N. Jeevanjee, An Introduction to Tensors and Group Theory for Physicists (second ed.), end of chapter problem 2.6 (p48)